# Variable Custom Fields in a Page in Silverstripe; Populate Table

Tags: database, content-management-system, silverstripe

How do I add variable custom fields in a page in Silverstripe?  For example if I created a custom field for "Hobbies", it is possible a person will have a several hobbies. And so I need the user to dynamically add another field to enter a hobby in the front end CMS. So maybe a button like "Add another hobby" the user can click in the CMS?

Another question is how do I populate a table in Silverstripe programmitically?

Comment: Would you please split wour two questions into two topics on stackoverflow?

Comment: What kind of field or relation is the "Hobbies"? Just a textfield, a has_one or a many_many? Could you provide some code? There are some possible solutions for this problem.

Comment: @wmk the hobby and person has many_many relationshionsip. One solution would be great please.

Comment: Did you see the lessons? http://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/working-with-data-relationships-many-many e.g. is about many_many relationships. If anything is still unclear please ask and provide what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you’ll need a `has_many` relationship on your page to a `Hobby` data object extension:

```
// HobbyPage.php
class HobbyPage extends Page {

    private static $has_many = array(
        'Hobbies' => 'HobbyPage'
    );

}

// Hobby.php
class Hobby extends DataObject {

    private static $has_one = array(
        'HobbyPage' => 'HobbyPage'
    );

    private static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Varchar(250)',
        // Any extra fields you want
    );

}
```

Depending on how complex you need the data to be you could handle adding in the CMS using a `GridField` or something like a tag field (https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-tagfield). Important thing is to have your underlying database structure correct (with as `has_many`) before worrying about how to store / retrieve data.

I believe the SilverStripe lessons (http://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons) cover data relationships and should help.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you may be looking for this module:

https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-multivaluefield

It allows you to store many values in a single field and gives you a few options for UI, including multiple dropdowns as you indicate in your question. Whether that's advisable or not depends on your specific scenario. Denormalization has pros and cons.

As howard10 said, tagfield may also be a good option for you.